# Lightweight lua objects vs. inheritance

Tags: lua

Although I did this a couple of times from scratch, still no solution really fits.

I'm using lua for scripting in my games. Lua holds the "prototypes" of the game elements, that are copied to each entity on it's creation. A prototype represents a class of objects ("Soldier with shotgun"). Also, each prototype may hold event hooks (OnDie, OnSpotEnemy, etc). Clearly it's a prototype, not the object that will be handled.

So, each time a hook is executed, I need to create an object to represent the calling entity (and any entities it interacts with) *only for the lifetime of a single script execution*. What it means is that a instance of the object lives in lua only for the time needed to run this script.

Simple execution of this idea wasn't much work -- I used `lightuserdata` to hold the C++ pointer to the entity encapsuled in a `being` class. To access the fields of the C++ object, I overloaded the metatable of `being`. However, the fact that the fields of the object are handled by a metatable practically breaks any reasonable implementation of inheritance.

I pondered with the usage of normal userdata, but I'm afraid that the dynamic allocation needed to run each script (some of them being ran each tick in the game loop) are going to ruin performance.

Any suggestions? Or maybe a better solution altogether?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use composition to model properties of complex entities rather than inheritance. More specifically, use a component-based design rather than an inheritance-based design for your entities. Each component has a known metadata table and your entity's metadata table just exposes a list of components.

- http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html
- http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/
- And lots of others if you search for "game components".

Comment: I can't, the C++ representation depends on inheritance, and honestly in this case composition doesn't make sense -- does a NPC include a Mobile which includes a Thing? Or does an Item include a Thing?

Comment: A Thing has-a Mobile (which I assume means physics) and has-a NPC (which I assume means AI or conversation). I don't know how Item fits into your hierarchy; usually, barring some in-world representation, a Thing has-a Inventory has-a Item; the item itself shares no base class with e.g. the player avatar.

Comment: Nope, thing is anything that can be placed on the map, mobile means something that can move (inteface has movement and the map doesn't cache position), NPC means the object can receive NPC events, has stats etc...

Comment: Item shares a lot with the player avatar -- a position, a map it belongs to, an event mechanism, a name (and other similar stats) and similar reaction to some events -- both are tangible things so both have physical statistics.

Comment: While I see where you're going, the problem is that due to composition, the C++ code will get really messy. We are talking about quite a big **existing** game. +1 anyway though -- the articles are an excellent read.

Comment: I think you will find, as argued in the linked articles, that the C++ code will get considerably cleaner by switching to components. (Your NPC class already sounds close to a blob.)

Comment: The motivation driving components is sound even if you (like me) find it pointless to have a "generic bag of crap" in each of your entities.  Consider: A "Thing" is anything in the world, it might have a position, it might not.  Give "Thing" a bunch of pointers instead of descendants; the player's AI* would point to the input handling.  Anything that can appear in the world has a Model*.  Anything that moves has MovementInfo*.  Anything that doesn't have one or more of these things just has a NULL in there.

Comment: The advantage of the "generic bag of crap" rather than a hardcoded set of pointers is that some of the crap can be entirely driven by an attached script, rather than C++ code. This was a motivation of doing it for Dungeon Siege (which is one of the main published references about it), and is also the core typing mechanism of Unity3D.

Comment: Agreed, I might consider it in the next project, however, I can't rewrite this one from scratch :/.

Answer (score 2):

If your normal userdata solution produces better code, I'd go with that.  Lua is so allocation-heavy anyway that you're probably not going to make a significant performance problem for yourself.  How many entities and events are you going to have anyway? 10s? 100s? You'll probably still be render-bound*.

And if you do encounter issues, there's ways to mitigate it through the use of different allocators, such as object pools, tiny allocators, and slot allocators.

Without firm profiler evidence either way, I'd always err on the side of cleaner code.

`*` warning vast over-generalisation based on knowing nothing about your game

Comment: Renderbound entities are not a problem. However the world is a breathing entity and in the background there's a lot of action. Consider the amount of alive entities in the 100000 range. However, the allocator idea seems quite reasonable, considering that each userdata would be the size of a pointer. I think boost has one that could be used out of the box.

Comment: You don't even need to use Boost, as they're not hard to implement by hand.  A small object allocator is an array of the size of your small object.  The freelist is the index of the first free item, and each free item is casted to an int and that is the index of the next free item.  When you want to allocate one item, just peel the first one off the list, construct-in-place, and you're done.  To free it, just destroy it, write the first free item's index into it, and then set firstfree to the index of the item.

Comment: You can also just plug in something like tcmalloc (http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) which has better support for small object allocation and see if it helps, no code changes necessary.

Comment: Also, see Modern C++ Design for Alexandrescu's Tiny Allocator.

Comment: @tenpn that's exactly what I was thinking about.  It's a great model to follow and doesn't even require too much mad template skills.

Comment: @tenpn, I actually have that one implemented somewhere :P